# C# to arduino communication

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, byte, communication

Good afternoon everyone,

I'm experimenting with serial communication between c# and arduino.
To understand how the comms work with regards to sending numbers (I know, there's alot being discussed already but bear with me) I want to send the value of a trackbar to the arduino, and then translate this number in movement of a servo.

If I understand correctly, integers can't be sent directly but have to be converted into bytes first.
So for this I would convert the numeric value of the trackbar into a byte array

in C# :

```
byte[] Numbers;
Numbers = BitConverter.GetBytes(trackBar1.Value);
```

Via serial communication I would send the value

```
port.Write(Numbers, 0, 1);
```

And this is where I'm going wrong I think
The trackbar value goes from 0 to 255, so I guess I'd need to know the bytes that equal 0 to 255 to be able to adjust the last number (in my example '1') to get the correct number after translation in Arduino?

As for Arduino, I would 'translate' the bytes as follows:

```
int IncomingValue = Serial.parseInt();
```

And then I'd like to use the IncomingValue for my servo.

My question is what I'm doing incorrectly.

thanks

Comment: why would you store a number in the range of 0-255 as in integer in the first place? Sorry I cannot make sense of your post.  what last number?

Comment: Sending *single byte* looks ok to me. [Serial.parseInt()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/parseint/) awaits for `long`, use byte-oriented functions if you expect single byte, try [Serial.readBytes()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readbytes/).

Comment: An integer is stored in c# as bytes so you really aren't doing a conversion.  The GetBytes method is just doing a cast since the serial port send method wants bytes.  Pase methods usually want string as inputs.  So on receive end you want : Int Numbers = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes)

Comment: @Piglet no worries, I understand I migth not make sense as I'm learning as I go. The idea is that I want to send whatever value I have on the trackbar to the arduino and use said value for my servo. The range of the trackbar is 0 (minimum value) to 255 (maximum value)

Comment: @Sinatr I see, thank you.Will play around with that :-)

Comment: @jdweng thank you. So if I undersand correctly, the way I'd have to handle it is first in c# I'd have to create an array of bytes which equals whatever number I have, to send through the port. Then translate this array in the Arduino IDE to get the number ?

Comment: Yes.  An int is four bytes so you send four bytes on the serial port.  Then receive four bytes a convert the bytes back to an int.

Comment: An `int` is not necessarily four bytes.  It might be in C#, but not necessarily so on the `arduino` part you're using.  Many arduino parts use a 16-bit integer representation. 
 And this question is not nearly complete, containing only three lines of source code.

Comment: @jdweng ok thank you.

Comment: @TomServo Thank you for your reply, I've read indeed the bytes not being the same everywhere, but my issue is more getting the basic understanding of serial comms with regards to ints. I also understand what you're saying with the source code not being complete, but I don't think it would add any value to my question as the lines I posted were the ones that needed clarification for myself.

Comment: @Quinten No, actually the bytes are the same virtually everywhere, most parts these days using 8-bit bytes (although some custom parts, like some of what I design, uses 9-bit bytes).  What often varies is the lengths and endianness of various larger-than-byte primitive types.  As to your question, there are literally hundreds of examples out on the web of how to do your simple task.

Comment: @TomServo ok thanks for the info. I'm not a programmer by trade as you may have noticed in my previous comments, I'm a bit further down the road with my learning and managed to get the servo working with the trackbar atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested in tinkering with c# to arduino serial communication (just desribing the issue I had) and sending a value of a trackbar to use in arduino:

make yourself a form project and name it whatever you like.
Then create a trackbar. I will create a trackbar with a minimum value of 0 and a maximum of 255 as follows:

```
trackbar1.Minimum = 0;
trackbar1.Maximum = 255;
trackBar1.TickFrequency = 10;   // this will set ticks every 10 units.
```

Now we can setup the actual communication between c# and arduino. I'll start with c#.

Opening a port:

```
  port = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600);   //Set your Arduino COM port and baud rate
            port.Open();
```

Now we also need to create an event to close the port when the program shuts:

```
 void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (port != null && port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Close();
            }
        }
```

Now we have set up the port, but we still need data to send. In our example we told we were going to send the value of the trackbar. To do this, click on your trackbar and find the trackBar1_Scroll event and double click it.
This basically creates the event of scrolling the trackbar and now we have to describe in this event what we want to happen.

We want to send the data of the trackbar via serial. The trackbar value is retrieved as follows:

```
trackbar1.value
```

Now we know how to retrieve the value, we have to look at the options of sending it, there's 3 options using `port.write()`, we'll use this later:

-Write(String)
-Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)
-Write(Char[], Int32, Int32)

but as I'm working with an int, I found that the second one was the one I needed.
As you can see we need a Byte array to be able to send this, so we will cast our trackbar data into a byte array by using BitConverter and declaring a byte array called Numbers:

```
byte[] Numbers = BitConverter.GetBytes(trackBar1.Value);
```

Now we have every element we need:

- The port which has been opened. We also described when to close it.
- The trackbar and its data to send.
- The data of the trackbar 'packaged' the correct way to be able to send it.

the only thing we didn't do is describe the scroll event, but now we have the correct data format, we can:

```
private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            byte[] Numbers = BitConverter.GetBytes(trackBar1.Value);

            port.Write(Numbers, 0, 1);

        }
```

so in c# our code will look like this:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            trackBar1.Minimum = 0;
            trackBar1.Maximum = 255;
            trackBar1.TickFrequency = 10;

            port = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600);//Set your board COM
            port.Open();

            this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form1_FormClosed);
           
        }
 
void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (port != null && port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Close();
            }
        }

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            byte[] Numbers = BitConverter.GetBytes(trackBar1.Value);

            port.Write(Numbers, 0, 1);

        }
```

As for arduino, all we need to do is:

A] Start our serial

B] Read the incoming data

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>                 // include the LCD library

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);     //define the LCD display

int Number;                               //define the number int (the one we'll store our received trackbar value in)
    
    void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(9600);           //A] Start our serial
    }
    
    void loop()
    {
      
       lcd.setCursor(0, 0);     // Set the LCD cursor at the top left corner

      if (Serial.available() > 0 ) {         //B] Read the incoming data
        nummer = Serial.read();              //
        lcd.print(nummer);                   //
      }                                      //
      else {};                               //
                      
   }
```

I used an LCD to read the data as I couldn't figure out a way to open the serial monitor with the serial communication between c# and arduino happening.
that's why I included an LCD.

I feel explaining this is beyond the scope of this little issue I had.

I hope this helps other beginners like me in the future.

thanks to those who were helpful!

Comment: This is a complete non-answer to a poor question.  You should delete it because it has no future value to readers of this site.

Comment: @TomServo I understand that this might come over as nonsense, but I do believe for absolute beginners that this may give them a nudge in the right direction. If you think this doesn't, which might be absolutely possible as you clearly have more experience in the matter, then I think it would make more sense that you provide better info instead of saying that it's a non-answer and a poor question.

All I'm trying to do is learn from scratch, not having any education in the matter whatsoever. Indeed the internet is full of answers but it gets difficult filtering out..